# executing a event at particular time

Tags: python, schedule

I have pygame code to display something on screen. The problem I am facing is that how can I generate an event at particular time read from file to pygame code. Following is my pygame code

```
 screen = pygame.display.set_mode([640,640])
 clock  = pygame.time.Clock()
 font   = pygame.font.SysFont("consolas", 25, True)
 pygame.display.set_caption("Test")
 count = 0
 done = False
 while not done:
     screen.fill(white)
     for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
             done = True
     f=open('input.txt')
     lines=f.readlines()
     model_no = int(lines[0])
     f.close()

     out2 = "MODEL NO."
     text = font.render(out2,True,(253,15,21))
     screen.blit(text, [320,200])

     count += 1
     out5 = "ACTUAL          %s"  %count
     text = font.render(out5, True, Color('red'))
     screen.blit(text, [320,500])

     clock.tick(4)
     pygame.display.flip()
```

I have a time saved in a file (for example '19:30:20'). How can I generate an event at this particular time which resets count value to 0 before it starts increments again. Is it possible to do it using apscheduler and how? Also the time in file can change thus if it changes the event should be generated at new time. Any ideas or solution which can help me solve my problem?

Comment: Is there any reason the time is in a file? It would be much easier to handle a time if it was a variable, then you don't need to keep checking the file to see if it changes.

Comment: Yes this code is actually only doing the work of displaying things while the time is received from client by the server application which saves it to a file.

Comment: ok what if I managed to handle time as variable then how can I generate event at that particular time to make count value 0.

Answer (score 0):

Read your time from the file and convert current time to string formatted in same manner:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
string_now = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Then use a loop to check if the current time equals your trig time:

```
while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        string_now = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        string_from_file = "10:07:01"
        #trig_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_from_file, '%H:%M:%S')
        if string_now == string_from_file:
            print "*"*50
            print "Wahoo!"
            print "*"*50
            break
        else:
            print "Not time yet"
            continue
```

I would probably put the above loop in a separate thread or process and do something to slow it down.  Like have it check once a minute or once every few minutes.  But if you really want to check and alarm down to the second then you might need to rethink some parts.  Opening, reading and closing a file this quickly is just going to cause problems.

You could also do the same as above with actual datetime objects.  Instead of converting current time to a string, convert your string_from_file to a datetime object.  Then perform the checks against the two datetime objects. (see the line I commented out to convert your string to a datetime object.

Comment: I have already tried your method but it is not working. I put the loop in separate thread but it missed out the time. Thus question is how much should I slow it down so that it doesn't miss out. Also, I need an accuracy of ~1 second

Comment: The above definitely works by itself, I'm guessing there's something else going on.  Any chance you can post more of your code?  I think there could be a couple tricky parts 1) getting your reset flag back to you main code to reset the counter 2) making sure 'string_now' and 'string_from_file' have the same format 3) making sure you're getting the correct line from your file which contains the time you're after

Answer (score 0):

catwalker333 provided not-so-bad answer. In my opinion, active waiting would do the trick in Pascal, not python.

I'd tell you to calculate difference in time between moment from file, and "now". It will tell you how much time is left, until event is generated. Substract few seconds from it, use `time.sleep(time_difference)`, and after that do the active waiting.

Why do I suggest substracting few seconds? Sleeping is kinda tricky, it MAY not wake up when it should (maybe a little earlier, maybe a little later). It is good for sleeping for long, not-really-precise amounts of time, but shouldn't be used when we need accuracy of ~1s.

You can parse time from file as shown by catwalker333, and substraction will give you a `timedelta`, which will give you number of seconds to sleep.

---

Why isn't sleeping accurate?

Well, first thing is GIL. It is released when sleeping, and acquiring it may be unavailable at the moment of waking up, so we may need to wait a little longer.

Another thing is computation time. When you're trying to compute difference between given time and "now" time, time flows (damn, too much "time" in time-related sequence :P ), so you should sleep even less time. How much less? God knows, devil suspects. It varies with every run, and is pretty unpredictable.

Comment: Problem is I need an accuracy of ~1 second

Comment: So, if event should be generated at 7PM and it is 5PM sleep for 1 hour 59 minutes and 40 seconds, than go to active waiting until it is time to generate your event. You'll spend way more time using processor, and have needed accuracy.